# Replace NSViewController under Swift2 Storyboard MAC OSX

Tags: xcode, macos, swift, storyboard, osx-elcapitan

I am new to Mac OSX and with Apple promoting the fact that the bodies of code are becoming similar decided to tell the folk I am writing code for we should be able to do a Mac OSX version.  iPhone and iPad versions are all good and about to release second version so no issues there.

So I am subclassing NSWindowController to get access to the Toolbar and worked out how to remove and add items on the toolbar, but for the life of me I can not get one NSViewController (firstViewController) to dismiss and bring up the second NSViewController (secondViewController) in the same NSWindowController.

So the 2 issues are that 
1. I want to be able to performSegueWithIdentifier from the first NSViewController in code and 
2. bring up the second NSViewController by replacing the first NSViewController in the same NSWindowController.

If I add a button to the firstViewController and put a segue to the secondViewController then when I select the button the secondViewController comes up just fine but in a seperate window not the same NSWindowController that I want it to and the firstViewController does not get replaced but stays in the NSWindowController.

So I know the segue idea will work but its not working in code and when I do insert the segue from a button it works but into a seperate NSViewController that is not part of the NSWindowController.

I am trying to find some programming guide from Apple on the issue but no luck so far.

Here is an overview from my Storyboard:

[image: Storyboard overview]

Here is my NSWindowController subclassed and the func loginToMe2Team is  trigger from the NSToolBar and its working just find as the print statements show up on the console.

```
import Cocoa

class me2teamWindowsController: NSWindowController {

@IBOutlet var mySignUp : NSToolbarItem!
@IBOutlet var myToolbar : NSToolbar!
let controller =  ViewController()

override func windowDidLoad() {
    super.windowDidLoad()
    print("window loaded")
}

override func windowWillLoad() {
    print("window will load")
}


@IBAction func logInToMe2Team(sender: AnyObject){

    controller.LogIn() //THIS IS THE FUNC I AM TESTING WITH

}

@IBAction func signUpToMe2Team(sender: AnyObject){

    controller.signUp()


}
```

Here is my NSViewController subclassed with the func LogIn.  Its getting selected just fine but the performSegueWithIdentifier is not.  And I did cut and past the Identifier to make absolutely sure it was the same.

```
import Cocoa
import WebKit

class ViewController: NSViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var theWebPage: WebView!
@IBOutlet weak var progressIndicator: NSProgressIndicator!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let urlString = "https://thewebpage.com.au"
    self.theWebPage.mainFrame.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: urlString)!))
}

override func viewDidAppear() {
}

func LogIn() {
    print("I logged in")
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("goToTeamPage", sender: self)
    //THIS IS THE BIT THATS NOT WORKING
}

func signUp() {
    print("I have to sign up now")
}

override var representedObject: AnyObject? {
    didSet {
    }
}

func webView(sender: WebView!, didStartProvisionalLoadForFrame frame: WebFrame!)
{
    self.progressIndicator.startAnimation(self)
}

func webView(sender: WebView!, didFinishLoadForFrame frame: WebFrame!)
{
    self.progressIndicator.stopAnimation(self)
}

}
```

[image]

Comment: Still really need an answer to this question if anyone has a solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use a custom segue class (or possibly `NSTabViewController` if it’s enough for your needs). Set the segue’s type to Custom, with your class name specified:

[image]

…and implement it. With no animation, it’s simple:

```
class ReplaceSegue: NSStoryboardSegue {
    override func perform() {
        if let src = self.sourceController as? NSViewController,
           let dest = self.destinationController as? NSViewController,
           let window = src.view.window {
            // this updates the content and adjusts window size
            window.contentViewController = dest
        }
    }
}
```

In my case, I was using a sheet and wanted to transition to a different sheet with a different size, so I needed to do more:

```
class ReplaceSheetSegue: NSStoryboardSegue {
    override func perform() {
        if let src = self.sourceController as? NSViewController,
           let dest = self.destinationController as? NSViewController,
           let window = src.view.window {
            // calculate new frame:
            var rect = window.frameRectForContentRect(dest.view.frame)
            rect.origin.x += (src.view.frame.width - dest.view.frame.width) / 2
            rect.origin.y += src.view.frame.height - dest.view.frame.height
            // don’t shrink visible content, prevent minsize from intervening:
            window.contentViewController = nil
            // animate resizing (TODO: crossover blending):
            window.setFrame(window.convertRectToScreen(rect), display: true, animate: true)
            // set new controller
            window.contentViewController = dest
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I will give it a try and get back to you.  Appreciate the response.

Comment: Thanks Vaclav, that fixed it.

Comment: HI Vaclav. Are you able to help with the other issue I had in that I can not perform the segue from func LogIn().  It works now just fine in the IBAction  button on the ViewController but not from the func LogIn().  Is there a way I can call the func LogIn() and it perfrom the custom Segue as I know the func is being called but it wont fire the performSegue.

Comment: My bet would be on mistyped identifier, or no identifier provided in the XIB file.

Comment: Thanks Vaclav,  I think its something to do with the sender aspect as both func and IBAction point to a 3rd func and still only the IBAction work.   I have another solution I will try, and update the question once I have cracked it.  Thanks again.